# Convert YYYYMMDD to day in presto/hive

Tags: sql, hive, presto

I have date column "YYYYMMDD", int type. I want to convert to "day" like 'monday'.

Comment: Hi, please read this: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post.

Answer (score 1):

this below sql might helpful for you.

```
hive>
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(20200802 as string),'yyyyMMdd'),'u') as weekdaynumber,
       CASE from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(20200802 as string),'yyyyMMdd'),'u')
           WHEN 1 THEN 'Monday'
           WHEN 2 THEN 'Tuesday'
           WHEN 3 THEN 'Wedneday'
           WHEN 4 THEN 'Thursday'
           WHEN 5 THEN 'Friday'
           WHEN 6 THEN 'Saturday'
           WHEN 7 THEN 'Sunday'
END AS day_of_week

OK
7       Sunday
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below in hive

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast('20200802' as string),'yyyyMMdd'),'EEEE') ;
```

this will return `Sunday` as the output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do this in Presto,  you can combine `cast` to `varchar` and then [`parse_datetime`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#parse_datetime). Since `parse_datetime` returns a `timestamp with time zone`, you need to use [`date`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date) to trim the parsed value to date part.

```
presto> SELECT date(parse_datetime(CAST(20200801 AS varchar), 'yyyyMMdd'));
   _col0
------------
 2020-08-01
```